# UK law report style' index of cases

Tags: indexing, legal-style

UK Law reports feature a list of cases referred to in the judgment at the beginning, alphabetised, but without page numbers and incorporated seamlessly into the running text (ie in the middle of the headnote).  This is seen in the image below:

I apologise for a basic question, but using imakeidx (or similar), how could I get a similar index that:

1. Lacks any page number or information after the case name
2. Occurs within and on the same page as running text

   3. Is typeset with similar margins etc as everything else in the running text
      [image: image of law report]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You need to create a table of cases in OSCOLA style. You can find an example of how to do this here: https://github.com/alexhaydock/LaTeX-OSCOLA/blob/master/template.tex

Comment: I need something similar but I would essay a guess that the ICLR does it manually. How far do you need to automate it? The trickiest part would be working out how to automatically identify an item in one sub-bibliography that is *not* in another (all other?) sub-bibliographies. I think it should be doable with biblatex's programming capability (or even with `datatool` and `newfile` packages - I use these to print a list of adhoc abbreviations used and their definition, in alphabetical order).

Answer (score 1):

Edit 3: `Biblatex`

Biblatex can do filtering.

Treating the lists as bibliographies in their own right, a judicious use of biblatex customizable categories achieves the desired result:

[image: biblatex filtering by category]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}



\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@jurisdiction{antaios85,
title          = {Antaios Compania Naviera S.A. v.
Salen Rederierna A.B. (The Nema)},
shorttitle     = {The Nema},
date           = {1985},
reporter       = {A.C.},
pages          = {191},
court          = {H.L.},
additionalreports = {[1984] 3 WLR 592 and (1984) 128 SJ 564
and [1984] 3 All ER 229 and
[1984] 2 Lloyd’s Rep 235},
keywords       = {gb},
}

@jurisdiction{corr08,
title        = {Corr v. I.B.C. Vehicles Ltd.},
keywords     = {gb},
date         = {2008},
number       = {[2008] UKHL 13},
journaltitle = {A.C.},
volume       = {1},
pages        = {884},
options      = {year-essential=true},
institution  = {HL},
shorttitle   = {Corr},
pagination   = {[]},
}

@jurisdiction{page96,
title         = {Page v Smith},
keywords     = {gb},
date          = {1996},
journaltitle  = {AC},
pages         = {155},
institution   = {HL},
}

@jurisdiction{barrett01a,
title        = {Barrett v Enfield LBC},
keywords     = {en},
date         = {2001},
journaltitle = {BMLR},
volume       = {49},
pages        = {1},
institution  = {HL},
}

@jurisdiction{stubbs90,
title        = {Stubbs v Sayer},
institution  = {CA},
date         = {1990-11-08},
keywords     = {en},
}

@jurisdiction{calvert02,
title        = {Calvert v Gardiner},
keywords     = {en},
number       = {[2002] EWHC 1394 (QB)},
institution  = {QB},
date         = {2002-01-01},
tabulate={caselistarg},
}

@jurisdiction{henly28,
title      = {Henly v Mayor of Lyme},
date       = {1828},
volume     = {5},
reporter   = {Bing},
pages      = {91},
keywords   = {en},
parvolume  = {130},
parreporter= {ER},
parpages   = {995},
tabulate={caselistarg},
}

@jurisdiction{churchnom,
title      = {Church v Brownewick},
date       = {1667},
volume     = {1},
reporter   = {Syd},
pages      = {334},
keywords   = {en},
tabulate={caselistarg},
}

@jurisdiction{churcher,
title      = {Church v Brownewick},
date       = {1667},
volume     = {1},
reporter   = {Syd},
pages      = {334},
keywords   = {en},
parvolume  = {82},
parreporter= {ER},
parpages   = {1140},
}

@jurisdiction{thom93,
title        = {The Queen v. Thomson},
keywords     = {gb},
date         = {1893},
journaltitle = {Q.B.D.},
volume       = {2},
pages        = {12},
options      = {year-essential=true},
institution  = {Crown Case Reserved},
shorttitle   = {Thomson},
pagination   = {[]},
}


@jurisdiction{mills,
title = {Mills v Mills},
date = {1938},
reporter = {C.L.R.},
pages = {150},
keywords = {au},
}

\end{filecontents}

\newcommand\mybibfilename{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=oscola,
   refsegment=section,    
    citetracker=false, %just for this example
%   ibidtracker=true,          
    indexing=cite,              
    backend=biber, 
    sorting=nty,
]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{\mybibfilename}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{arguendo}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{judgment}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{fllwd}



\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}

\usepackage[splitindex, nonewpage, noautomatic]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=arg, title={\ }, columns=1]
\makeindex[name=caselistarg, title={}, columns=1]


\defbibnote{injdgmnt}{The following cases are referred to in the judgment:}

\defbibnote{inarg}{The following cases were additionally referred to in argument:}

%remove full stop at end of an entry in the bibliography
\renewcommand*\finentrypunct{}

%==================================
\begin{document}
\textit{Companies} -- a director may act against the interests of a class of shareholders. 
{
\renewcommand*\finentrypunct{, followed.}
\printbibliography[
    category=fllwd,
    heading=none,
]
}

%\fullcite{mills}, followed.
%\smallskip

\printbibliography[
    category=judgment,
    heading=none,
    prenote=injdgmnt,
]

\printbibliography[
    category=arguendo,
    notcategory=judgment,
    heading=none,
    prenote=inarg,
]

\section*{Argument}
x\autocite{page96}
x\autocite{corr08}
x\autocite{antaios85}
x\autocite{barrett01a}
x\autocite{stubbs90}
x\autocite{calvert02}
x\autocite{henly28}

\addtocategory{arguendo}{page96, corr08, antaios85, barrett01a, stubbs90, calvert02, henly28}

\section*{Judgment}
y\autocite{churcher}
y\autocite{henly28}
z\nocite{mills}

\addtocategory{judgment}{calvert02, henly28}

\addtocategory{fllwd}{mills}

\end{document}
```

As with all combinatorial matters, several paths may lead to the same result.

Here, three categories were defined

```
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{arguendo}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{judgment}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{fllwd}
```

All the cases in argument were added to the `arguendo` category with:

```
\addtocategory{arguendo}{page96, corr08, antaios85, barrett01a, stubbs90, calvert02, henly28}
```

In the judgment, the case followed was added to the `fllwd` category:

```
\addtocategory{fllwd}{mills}
```

and the referred-to cases were added to the `judgment` category:

```
\addtocategory{judgment}{calvert02, henly28}
```

For typesetting the lists (which is what a bibliography is, in the end), the additional-cases-in-argument bibliography had a prenote `inarg` defined as:

```
\defbibnote{inarg}{The following cases were additionally referred to in argument:}
```

and the bibliography was set to print with no heading, with the prenote, and filtered to including cases in the argument category and excluding cases in the judgment category:

```
\printbibliography[
    category=arguendo,
    notcategory=judgment,
    heading=none,
    prenote=inarg,
]
```

The usual `.` at the end of each bib item, governed by the `\finentrypunct` command, was defined to nothing with:

```
\renewcommand*\finentrypunct{}
```

Similar technique for the cases referred to in the judgment (`category=judgment`).

For the single-item bibliography, being the case in the followed category (`category=fllwd`), the final "punctuation" was redefined to ", followed." with:

```
\renewcommand*\finentrypunct{, followed.}
```

and the scope of the redefinition was kept constrained to just that bibliography by a pair of surrounding braces `{` and `}`:

```
{
\renewcommand*\finentrypunct{, followed.}
\printbibliography[
    category=fllwd,
    heading=none,
]
}
```

And that's it.

Compilation workflow is: xelatex/biber/xelatex. Much simpler than when index files are involved.

If it is required that a case be listed in the headnote without being cited in the body of the text, the `\nocite{`*ref*`}` command will put *ref* into the processing stream without there being a citation in the text, and the bibliography/listing will pick it up (given the categories and filters are correctly defined, assigned, and appropriate).

---

Earlier response, for historical interest

Edit 2: Custom lists and index files

[image: headnote case list]

Using `imakeidx`, with a named index file for each list, you can, taking `arg` as an example name:

- give the index no title and make it one column instead of the usual two with `\makeindex[name=arg, title={\ }, columns=1]`
- remove all the title spacing etc with `titlesec` package commands

```
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{}{}{}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\renewcommand\indexspace{\vspace{0pt}}
```

- add a prologue to the list, while we're at it: `\indexprologue[\medskip]{The following cases were referred to in argument:}`
- print the named index with `\printindex[arg]`
- define an empty style file (essentially, print no commas or dots), call it `oscolaplain.mst`, consisting of:

```
delim_0 ""
delim_1 ""
delim_2 ""
delim_n ""
delim_r ""
delim_t ""
```

(we'll come back to that file later)

- define a command `mygobble`

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\let\mygobble\@gobble
\makeatother
```

- which, when applied in the indexing command that is sending an entry to the named index, will swallow the page number:

```
\index[arg]{\cite{corr08}|mygobble}
```

- add the rest of the `\index` commands; since page numbers are irrelevant, the commands can go anywhere
- then compile in this sequence (I use xelatex):

  - xelatex
  - biber
  - splitindex -- -s oscolaplain.mst -c
  - xelatex
  - biber
  - xelatex

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@jurisdiction{antaios85,
title          = {Antaios Compania Naviera S.A. v.
Salen Rederierna A.B. (The Nema)},
shorttitle     = {The Nema},
date           = {1985},
reporter       = {A.C.},
pages          = {191},
court          = {H.L.},
additionalreports = {[1984] 3 WLR 592 and (1984) 128 SJ 564
and [1984] 3 All ER 229 and
[1984] 2 Lloyd’s Rep 235},
keywords       = {gb},
}

@jurisdiction{corr08,
title        = {Corr v. I.B.C. Vehicles Ltd.},
keywords     = {gb},
date         = {2008},
number       = {[2008] UKHL 13},
journaltitle = {A.C.},
volume       = {1},
pages        = {884},
options      = {year-essential=true},
institution  = {HL},
shorttitle   = {Corr},
pagination   = {[]},
}

@jurisdiction{page96,
title         = {Page v Smith},
keywords     = {gb},
date          = {1996},
journaltitle  = {AC},
pages         = {155},
institution   = {HL},
}

@jurisdiction{barrett01a,
title        = {Barrett v Enfield LBC},
keywords     = {en},
date         = {2001},
journaltitle = {BMLR},
volume       = {49},
pages        = {1},
institution  = {HL},
}

@jurisdiction{stubbs90,
title        = {Stubbs v Sayer},
institution  = {CA},
date         = {1990-11-08},
keywords     = {en},
}

@jurisdiction{calvert02,
title        = {Calvert v Gardiner},
keywords     = {en},
number       = {[2002] EWHC 1394 (QB)},
institution  = {QB},
date         = {2002-01-01},
tabulate={caselistarg},
}

@jurisdiction{henly28,
title      = {Henly v Mayor of Lyme},
date       = {1828},
volume     = {5},
reporter   = {Bing},
pages      = {91},
keywords   = {en},
parvolume  = {130},
parreporter= {ER},
parpages   = {995},
tabulate={caselistarg},
}

@jurisdiction{churchnom,
title      = {Church v Brownewick},
date       = {1667},
volume     = {1},
reporter   = {Syd},
pages      = {334},
keywords   = {en},
tabulate={caselistarg},
}

@jurisdiction{churcher,
title      = {Church v Brownewick},
date       = {1667},
volume     = {1},
reporter   = {Syd},
pages      = {334},
keywords   = {en},
parvolume  = {82},
parreporter= {ER},
parpages   = {1140},
}

@jurisdiction{thom93,
title        = {The Queen v. Thomson},
keywords     = {gb},
date         = {1893},
journaltitle = {Q.B.D.},
volume       = {2},
pages        = {12},
options      = {year-essential=true},
institution  = {Crown Case Reserved},
shorttitle   = {Thomson},
pagination   = {[]},
}


@jurisdiction{mills,
title = {Mills v Mills},
date = {1938},
reporter = {C.L.R.},
pages = {150},
keywords = {au},
}

\end{filecontents}

\newcommand\mybibfilename{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=oscola,    
    citetracker=false, %just for this example
%   ibidtracker=true,          
    indexing=cite,              
    backend=biber, 
]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{\mybibfilename}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono}[Colour=blue]

\usepackage[splitindex, nonewpage, noautomatic]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=arg, title={\ }, columns=1]
\makeindex[name=caselistarg, title={}, columns=1]

\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\let\mygobble\@gobble
\makeatother


\newcommand\mystart{%
\vspace{12pt}
\noindent\textit{Start}
\vspace{0.5ex}
\hrule
\vspace{12pt}}

\newcommand\myend{%
\vspace{12pt}
\hrule
\vspace{0.5ex}\noindent\textit{End}
\vspace{12pt}}



%==================================
\begin{document}



\lipsum[5-7]
{
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{}{}{}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\renewcommand\indexspace{\vspace{0pt}}
\indexprologue[\medskip]{The following cases were referred to in argument:}
 \printindex[arg]
}


\textit{arguendo}\index[arg]{\cite{churcher}|mygobble}


 y\index[arg]{\cite{page96}|mygobble}
 y\index[arg]{\cite{corr08}|mygobble}
 y\index[arg]{\cite{antaios85}|mygobble}
 y\index[arg]{\cite{barrett01a}|mygobble}
 y\index[arg]{\cite{stubbs90}|mygobble}
 y\index[arg]{\cite{calvert02}|mygobble}
 y\index[arg]{\cite{henly28}|mygobble}
$\leftarrow$ text with index entries attached.


\end{document}
<>><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>><>
```

If the list is reasonably short, a manual method would be to define a custom list in the preamble, with suitable layout settings:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{hncaselist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[hncaselist,1]{label=,
noitemsep,
%labelindent=1em,
leftmargin=2em,
%labelsep=\itemindent+2em,
itemindent=-2em,
}
```

and use it like so:

```
\noindent The following cases were referred to in argument:

\begin{hncaselist}
\item \cite{page96}
\item \cite{corr08}
\item \cite{antaios85}
\item \cite{barrett01a}
\item \cite{stubbs90}
\item \cite{calvert02}
\item \cite{henly28}
\end{hncaselist}
```

Only, it displays as it is - you would have to manually arrange the entries into alphabetical order.

[image: with a custom list]

On another note, `oscola` package makes use of a `tabulate=` key inside the bibentry to send the item directly to the named index, but at that level, the output is in fact a table of cases in terms of formatting, and italics don't show (as is the intention).

`Biblatex` allows programming, so a code block could be written that does as requested - that will be the next step.

---

Initial response:

Apologies - not an answer. The beginning of one.

The headnote packs in a lot of information, and basic questions take the most words to answer, but for the very very first step, if a list is to be used, an inline list would flow with the paragraph settings, and with its item label being a newline command, the layout could work.

For example, using `enumitem` package to define a custom list:

[image: inline list using newline]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{hncaselist}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[hncaselist,1]{label=\ \\}

\newcommand\longtext{text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text. }

\begin{document}
\noindent Cases referred to in X:

\begin{hncaselist}
\item Case A \longtext
\item Case B \longtext
\item Case C \longtext
\item Case D \longtext
\item Case E \longtext
\end{hncaselist}

\end{document}
```

Next step (or partial alternative) is: `biblatex` can pour items into (customised) lists, so the headnote case lists would, in effect, be mini-bibliographies, filtered by, say, keywords (added during citation, perhaps??). Since a bibliography is just a list, its margin, item indentation, etc are all adjustable, and `biblatex` can take care of the sorting (by title).

I need to explore.